# Compiling JasperReports automatically on change

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I am working on a web application. We are using jasperreports. Compiling jasperreports on every call is an overhead and takes considerable time (4-7 seconds). We thought of precompiling the jrxmls using Spring but still have the ability to re-generate if the jrxml is changed/modified.
Has anybody done this before? If yes, how.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can schedule a timer which re-compiles new jasper reports every X hours ([check here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html))
- You can load the jrxml as `File` and check its `lastModified()`, store it in a database (or a `HashMap`), and on each subsequent need for the jrxml to compare the `lastModified()` to the value in the database / `HashMap` and recompile it only if they differ
- combine the two methods above
- create a simple interface (a password-protected page) that lists all jrxml files with a button "compile", so that whenever you change something, you go to that page and indicated which jrxmls should be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your application, but you could look at using JasperServer. This web app has a repository and processes that manage JRXML content and compilation. You could access the app via web services.